# Python/Kivy - How to "connect" a function and a label in kv/py files

Tags: python, kivy

I created a counter inside a class to increment the value of `count`

```
count = 0

class LifeCounterApp(App):
    def incr(n):
        global count 
        count += 1
        return count
```

I have a kv file in which I am creating the structure of my app.

What I want to do: the button "+" inside my app has to update the value of the Label.

Example: the label has default value `0`. If I click on the button the label has to change its value to `1` and so on.

My questions:

1) How to take the value of the label from the .py file?

2) The way in which I am calling the function `incr` is correct? Because actually clicking on the button nothing happens.

```
Button:
    text: "+"
    on_release:
        app.incr()
Label:
    text: app.count (?)
```

Hope that my question is clear and well formulated.

Comment: Did you go through the [pong tutorial](https://kivy.org/docs/tutorials/pong.html)? It should help you with your question.

Comment: I'll go through it! Thank you for your suggestion!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use [NumericProperty](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.properties.html#kivy.properties.NumericProperty) for that and not a Python global variable.

Example:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty
from kivy.lang import Builder


Builder.load_string('''
<LifeCounter>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"

        Button:
            text: "+"
            on_release: root.count += 1
        Label:
            id: l_label
            text: str(root.count)

''')


class LifeCounter(BoxLayout):
    count = NumericProperty(0)
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(LifeCounter, self).__init__(**kwargs)

class DemoApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return LifeCounter()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    DemoApp().run()
```

If you want to use `incr` method to increase the value of `count` you can do it:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty
from kivy.lang import Builder


Builder.load_string('''
<LifeCounter>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"

        Button:
            text: "+"
            on_release: root.incr()
        Label:
            id: l_label
            text: str(root.count)

''')


class LifeCounter(BoxLayout):
    count = NumericProperty(0)
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(LifeCounter, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def incr(self):
        self.count += 1

class DemoApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return LifeCounter()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    DemoApp().run()
```

Comment: Got it! Thanks a lot!